# ASP.NET 6 API with ReactJS Client, handling Null and Undefined (not existing property) in Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

Good practice would be set parameter to null, when it is sent as null and do nothing with that when it is just not sent in request:

```
//Lets take an sample object from Database
User
{
  Age = 10;
  Size = 180;
}
```

```
//para-request
... {"User":{"Age":15} ...
```

it should change object to

```
//Lets take an sample object from Database
User
{
  Age = 10;
  Size = 180;
}
```

but

```
//para-request
... {"User":{"Age":15, "Size":null} ...
```

It should change object to

```
User
{
  Age = 10;
  Size = null;
}
```

The problem is that in ASP.Net and C# both requests comes to user as `null` in `Size` property. There is no simply way to recognize intentions of client.

How you cope with that?

Comment: Are you using EFCore? In your controller, are you binding the same user you send to database?

Comment: of course no. i have DTO, and yes im using efc, but as i mentioned its para-code, not my object from business project lol

Comment: How do you map dto to model? And how do you update that model in efcore?

Comment: @PedroRamon i have own mapper im creating and doing better from years. It works fine, i don't like automapper. How im updating? Its depends, but example:

 `item.Number = request.Number.HasValue ? request.Number.Value : item.Number;`